# Ruby/Sinatra/erb: save html fle

Tags: ruby, sinatra, erb

i wrote a website which shows the status of our api.

- endpoints.rb returns an hash with fine and bad endpoints
- apiStatusWebsite.rb is using endpoints.rb and renders status.erb

Code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'endpoints.rb'  


def updateStatus                
    get '/status' do

        endpointObject = Endpoints.new(getApiServerURL("qa"))
        result = endpointObject.checkApiStatus() 

        erb :status, :locals => { :apiData => result} 

    end
end
```

- status.erb with the html content

Problems:

1) the api allows 100 requests per 100 sec. when 3 people are calling the api status site, then the server makes 45 requests per user to the api -> server is banned for 100 sec and the status site is useless.

2) i could send a special header for problem 1 but then the status site could be misused for putting load on the api (unlikely but still possible)

possible solution:

/status just shows the api status but is not calling `endpointObject.checkApiStatus()`. this checking process should happen automatically every 2min somewhere in the background and creating a html file. this html file would be loaded from apiStatusWebsite2.rb

```
 require 'sinatra'

 get '/status' do

   send_file 'status.html'

 end
```

but how to save this html file which the current apiStatusWebsite.rb renders?

Comment: Why not just cache the response from the API? No need to save an HTML file.

Comment: thx gonna try, but can you also tell me how to use caching with sinatra, I am new this.

Answer (score 0):

You need some way to persist the values that come back from the API. Using an HTML file is a valid way, but there are better options. Better would be to only dump the response sans HTML, but even better than that would be to hold it in memory and only dump it when the app is closing or there haven't been calls for a while. You don't have to dump to a file either, you could use a database or any kind of persistent store. [There are libraries that will handle or help with this](http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=cache). Take a look at [some of these libraries too](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached#See_also), and then you'll have a better idea of things you might want to try.

Also, consider caching the responses from Sinatra to stop hitting the API so often, see [this article that gives a quick intro to caching responses with Sinatra](https://mutelight.org/http-caching) and [Cache Control in the Sinatra docs](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Cache%20Control)